# What is the "down" property in jQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to optimize the animation for a large scrollable jQuery UI Accordion. The documentation mentions that the [animate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-animate) option accepts an object as argument

> Object: Animation settings with easing and duration properties.
> Blockquote
>
> - Can also contain a *down property* with any of the above options.
> - "Down" animations occur when the panel being activated has a lower index than the currently active panel.

What is the *down property* or *down animation* ?

Also, while searching, I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15413662/2333214) which uses options such as  `autoHeight` and `clearStyle`, which i couldn't find in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/). Are these deprecated or do they exist without documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the [Accordion example](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#entry-examples). The down property is used to specify a **different** animation than the *up* animation, which is specified by the animate property. Take the example and exchange line 39 with the following snippet:

```
<script>
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    animate: {
      easing: 'linear',
      duration: 100,
      down: {
        easing: 'swing',
        duration: 900
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Easings are explained at [api.jqueryui.com](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) and if you open the modified example in the browser, the most obvious difference between the *up* and *down* animation is the duration.

*autoHeight* and [*clearStyle*](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5867) got [deprecated](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-autoheight-clearstyle-and-fillspace-options-merged-into-heightstyle). In the new versions *heightStyle* should suffice for your usecases. *heightStyle* is illustrated as an [Accordion example](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height).